# Object Looking Skewed After Essential Matrix Calculation and Projection

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to calculate an essential and a projection matrix from two images. I  will then use them to project a 3D object onto the image. The two images I used are

[image]
[image]

I picked a few pixel correspondences, and fed that to a SVD based least square mechanism which the books say gives me the essential matrix. I used the code below for this task (code is based mostly on *Eric Solem's Programming Computer Vision with Python* book):

```
import scipy.linalg as lin
import pandas as pd

def skew(a):
    return np.array([[0,-a[2],a[1]],[a[2],0,-a[0]],[-a[1],a[0],0]])

def essential(x1,x2):
    n = x1.shape[1]
    A = np.zeros((n,9))
    for i in range(n):
        A[i] = [ x1[0,i]*x2[0,i], \
          x1[0,i]*x2[1,i], \
          x1[0,i]*x2[2,i], \
          x1[1,i]*x2[0,i], \
          x1[1,i]*x2[1,i], \
          x1[1,i]*x2[2,i], \
          x1[2,i]*x2[0,i], \
          x1[2,i]*x2[1,i], \
          x1[2,i]*x2[2,i]]

    U,S,V = lin.svd(A)
    F = V[-1].reshape(3,3)
    return F

def compute_P_from_essential(E):
    U,S,V = lin.svd(E)
    if lin.det(np.dot(U,V))<0: V = -V
    E = np.dot(U,np.dot(np.diag([1,1,0]),V))        
    Z = skew([0,0,-1])
    W = np.array([[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])    
    P2 = [np.vstack((np.dot(U,np.dot(W,V)).T,U[:,2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U,np.dot(W,V)).T,-U[:,2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U,np.dot(W.T,V)).T,U[:,2])).T,
          np.vstack((np.dot(U,np.dot(W.T,V)).T,-U[:,2])).T]
    return P2


points = [ \
  [266,163,296,160],[265,237,297,266],\
  [76,288,51,340],[135,31,142,4],\
  [344,167,371,156],[48,165,71,164],\
  [151,68,166,56],[237,26,259,19],\
  [226,147,254,140]]

df = pd.DataFrame(points)
df['uno'] = 1.
x1 = np.array(df[[0,1,'uno']].T)
x2 = np.array(df[[2,3,'uno']].T)
print x1
print x2
E = essential(x1,x2)
P = compute_P_from_essential(E)

import pandas as pd

x0 = 3.; y0 = 1.; z0 = 1.

print df.shape
e = 1
cube = [[x0,y0,z0],[x0+e,y0,z0],[x0+e,y0+e,z0],[x0,y0+e,z0],
        [x0,y0,z0+e],[x0+e,y0,z0+e],[x0+e,y0+e,z0+e],[x0,y0+e,z0+e]]
cube = pd.DataFrame(cube)
cube['1'] = 1.

xx = np.dot(P[1], cube.T) * 100.
xx[1,:] = 360-xx[1,:] 
#xx = xx / xx[2]
print xx[0].shape
plt.plot(xx[0], xx[1],'.')
plt.xlim(0,640)
plt.ylim(0,360)
```

I calculated the essential matrix, then the projection matrix, then used that to project a 3D cube. The result:

[image]

This looks skewed, I am not sure why this happened. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you are computing the essential matrix using exactly 9 points. You can do this using only 8 (since scale is a free parameter, you can multiply the essential by a scalar and it will stay the same so you can fix one of the parameters and just use 8 points, but I digress.) However, in practice this is a very bad idea because your 8 points might have poor spatial configuration. So what you want to do is to select N matches (600 for example), and use an algorithm like [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) to determine the best Essential matrix. But aside from that, what I'd recommend to debug such applications is this: compute the [Fundalental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) matrix **F** based on the Essential you just computed. Now you can select a point in image 1 and then display the corresponding epipolar line in the second one. That will help you visually evaluate and thus debug the estimation of the Essential.